# Font family in SASS 7-1 Architecture pattern

Tags: reactjs, sass, font-family

I am doing a react project and I have to add mistral font-family. I know how to load the font-family, but is there a single file where to add it, if we are using the 7-1 architecture pattern?
My current scss folder structure is below:

```
1)Abstracts
 -_functions.scss
 -_mixins.scss
 -_variables.scss
2)base
 -_animations.scss
 -_base.scss
 -_typography.scss
 -_utilities.scss
3)components
 -_button.scss
 -_forms.scss
 -_login.scss
 -_product.scss
4)layouts
 -_footer.scss
 -_grid.scss
 -_header.scss
5)pages
 -_landing.scss
6)themes
7)vendors
 -_icons.scss
main.scss
```

Comment: I load my fonts in `typography.scss`. But don't know whether is it the right approach or not.

Comment: It shoutld go into `typography.scss` within `/base`